# How to reach Dudhsagar Falls by Scooter in Monsoon Season?

Tags: india, goa-india

i am newly married, and my wife love to trip dudhsagar falls on bike in monsoon in goa, let me know if its possible to visit dudhsagar falls in moonsoon. i check some guide about dudhsagar route like
[Dudhsagar Route Guide](https://tripraja.com/dudhsagar-trip-routes-guide-reach-dudhsagar-falls/) but there is nothing about timing of moonsoon season, or anything information if we can visit by scooter ?

please guide me.

Answer (score 2):

Well you You cannot travel to the dudhsagar falls by bike, you can only go as far as the park entrance and then you have to hire a jeep. The the road to the park is very, very busy with lots of lorries. I dont like travelling it by car to be honest. for more information please check on official dudhsagar falls website http://dudhsagar-falls.com/dudhsagar-falls-guide-how-to-reach/

Comment: You can not enter inside mollem national park with scooter or with your private vehicle. You have to book jeep safari ticket from tripraja.com website which cost Rs 700 per head or for full day trip with Rs. 1550 per head